# implement SLComposeViewController into Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, slcomposeviewcontroller

i can't seem to get the SLComposeViewController to come from a button on a cocos2D layer. If you could see anything that would stop this working please tell. Any help would be appreciated: N.B. viewController is a UIViewController

```
-(void)sceneSelect
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Twitter Message"];

    NSString *serviceType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SLServiceTypeTwitter"];


    if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:serviceType])
    {
        SLComposeViewController *tweetController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:serviceType];
        [tweetController setInitialText:message];

        tweetController.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){


            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone){
               //NSLog call
            }
            else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled){
               //NSLog call
            }

            [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
        };

        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:viewController.view];
        [viewController presentViewController:tweetController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter" message:@"Twitter not working" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d 2.0 then use navigation controller in AppDelegate

```
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[app navController] presentModalViewController:tweetController animated:YES];
```

HERE IS MY FULL TWITTER CODE:  http://pastebin.com/hpRRJM1n

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that, it works well for UIActivityView but can't get it to work for SLComposeViewController, thats why I tried the above. I will keep trying and see what I can get otherwise I will run with the UIActivityView. Any other insights would be great.